# Efficient way to compute covariance matrix of Vector Autoregressive Process of order 1 (VAR)

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression, high-dimensional, matrix-inverse

For a VAR process
$$
X_t = A_1 X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
$$

The covariance of $X_t$ can be computed in the following way:
$$
\text{vec}(\Sigma) = (I -(A \otimes A))^{-1} \text{vec}(\Sigma_{\epsilon})
$$
For large dimensions computing $(I -(A \otimes A))^{-1}$ is computationally expensive. I want to know if there are efficient ways of computing this. It is mentioned in the book by Lutkepohl that the paper Barone (1987) provides a way that avoids the inversion. I was wondering if there is an R package that implements an efficient way.

Comment: Can you give a more precise reference for Barone (1987)?  Which book by Lutkepohl? This one? Barone, Piero. 1987. “A Method for Generating Independent Realizations of a Multivariate Normal Stationary and Invertible ARMA(p, q) Process.” Journal of Time Series Analysis 8 (2): 125–30. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1987.tb00426.x.

Comment: Have you read the Barone paper? "Is there an R package that implements ..." is off-topic for both CrossValidated and StackOverflow, although if you started on an implementation of the Barone algorithm and got stuck partway you could definitely ask for help on Stack Overflow ...